# How can i get last(just before new line starts) cursor position of current line in EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, cursor-position

for example:-
“The greatness of a man is not in how much wealth he acquires, but in his integrity and his ability to affect those around him positively”

i want to get cursor position after 'and' in above text?

to get current cursor line i am using below method :-

```
public int getCurrentCursorLine(EditText editText)
    {
       int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
       Layout layout = editText.getLayout();

       if (!(selectionStart == -1))
       return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);

       return -1;
    }
```

But now i want end of line cursor position so i can fill the space between current cursor position and end of line cursor position.

Thanks, Nishu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want a method however, that you can call whenever you like:

```
private int getLastLineBreak(EditText editText) {
    int currentCursorPos = editText.getSelectionStart();
    Editable s = editText.getText();
    for (int i = currentCursorPos; i > 0; i--) {
        if (s.chartAt(i) == '\n') {
            return = i;   
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will return the last line break character `\n`, starting at the current cursor position and cycling back until either one is found, or position `0` is reached.

Comment: would prefer to call getLastLineBreak() method, let me try it out, will give you feedback if its worked :), i think this methods returns every line's last position but i want current line's last position, where cursor currently exist

Comment: @Nishusharma I've made an update to my answer that will start cycling back from the current cursor position, and stop at the last line break.

Comment: you can upvote my question so i can accept your answer :)